# I've already tried everything but my fluid simulation still not working

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new on blender, I'm trying to simulate a liquid in a glass but when I set all for the simulation nothing happen and I don't understand why; I've already tried to apply scale and other forms of transformations but nothing changed.

Heres the [blender project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CiWStNQx8u9bLeAQw0yX5H13jzFkTbCj/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: have you baked? , if yes then look if you have the cache set ad modular

Comment: it appears that you flow type was set to geometry , it is supposed to be set as inflow

Comment: Yes I baked yet but nothing happens (setting the cache to normal, I've tried All as well), I don't want to generate continuously the fluid, I would simply simulate the milk inside the glass, It seems like there is something wrong with the project settings or with the geometry of the milk :\
I've tried to create a new project, copy and paste the glass and the milk inside, try to generate the fluid from there and it's work.
So, what did I do wrong with the first attempt?

Comment: dont really know , by the way u got it , so leave it